# Get records in MS flow from Dynamics CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm, power-automate

I am new to CRM and flow and in building a flow using MS flow, I need to get a record from Dynamics CRM equivalent to below SQL query -

```
select * from contacts where emailId = '<email id>'
```

Can you please help me to understand that how can I achieve this. I tried using List records feature but it threw an error that OData query is not correct. Image of flow is attached.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's working, I just had to put the parameter supplied in the single quote like -

```js
emailaddress1 eq '<Customer email>'
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the issue you are facing is with Filter query, Flow is not throwing an Error.

- I tried to replicate the Flow on my Instance/org.
- The issue is see is your filter filed "emailadress" should be selected from CRM i.e from system.
- It is not mapped from CRM rather you wrote it per hand.
- Click on Filter query it will open the dialog from where you could map the
  fields. Screenshot below will help you understand more.

[image]